# AngularFire error callback function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I use a simple AngularJS service to detect if the user is logged in or not using the **authenticated** key stored in the local storage. If the user is authenticated, then the app reaches firebase to grab the data.

This works fine for logging in users and logging them out. The problem is when the the session expires automatically, the app tries to grab the data without knowing that the session has expired and that returns an error due to the security rules.

```
$firebase(dataBase.child(permanentStorage['uid']).child('Notes')).$asArray();
// var permanentStorage = window.localStorage;
```

I couldn't find any ways to add a callback function to the code above.

Comment: Are you looking to get notified when `$asArray()` loads the data?

Comment: no when it is unable to load the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the methods return a promise. Promises provide a success and error callback. The `$loaded` method is triggered after data is received from the server, so it makes a great use case for your request:

```
var list = $firebase(dataBase.child(permanentStorage['uid']).child('Notes')).$asArray();    
list.$loaded().catch(function(err) {
   console.error(err);
});
```

However, Firebase will raise a console.warn or console.error on any security error (failure to retrieve data), so this shouldn't be necessary.